# How to get a RPM package name required for FONTS installation on Red Hat Linux?

Tags: rhel, rpm, fonts

Is there a link which will give me the list of RPM packages available for Red hat Linux? and how do I pick up which RPM package for what purpose?

I need some BARCODE fonts to be installed on Linux server (Code 128, Code 39 fonts). I need these fonts to be picked by the application reports which will print the barcode for me on the report.

Comment: possibly helpful: http://www.azalea.com/barcode-fonts/

Comment: Thanks ! Azalea says that we should contact them for installation of barcode fonts on the Linux/UNIX OS.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a link which will give me the list of RPM packages available for Red hat Linux?

The `yum list` command will provide you a list of all available packages, and `yum search` will let you search for packages.  `yum list installed` will show you all the packages currently installed on your system.

For example:

```
yum search font
```

> and how do I pick up which RPM package for what purpose?

The `yum info` command can give you information about a package.  For example:

```
$ yum info openssh
Name        : openssh
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 6.6.1p1
Release     : 33.el7_3
Size        : 438 k
Repo        : rhelosp-rhel-7.3-server
Summary     : An open source implementation of SSH protocol versions 1 and 2
URL         : http://www.openssh.com/portable.html
License     : BSD
Description : SSH (Secure SHell) is a program for logging into and executing
            : commands on a remote machine. SSH is intended to replace rlogin
            : and rsh, and to provide secure encrypted communications between
            : two untrusted hosts over an insecure network. X11 connections and
            : arbitrary TCP/IP ports can also be forwarded over the secure
            : channel.
            : 
            : OpenSSH is OpenBSD's version of the last free version of SSH,
            : bringing it up to date in terms of security and features.
            : 
            : This package includes the core files necessary for both the
            : OpenSSH client and server. To make this package useful, you should
            : also install openssh-clients, openssh-server, or both.
```

> I need some BARCODE fonts to be installed on Linux server (Code 128, Code 39 fonts). I need these fonts to be picked by the application reports which will print the barcode for me on the report.

I don't believe there are any barcode fonts packaged in Red Hat Linux.  However, you can simply download appropriate fonts from elsewhere and install them yourself.  There are instructions for installing fonts [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Desktop_Migration_and_Administration_Guide/configure-fonts.html).

Comment: Thanks larsks! This was useful, as am not a Linux Admin and it provided knowledge on the subject.